# Has anyone heard of this sefer?

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries

There is a side note on the side of Yerushalmi Terumos 7:2 “עיין במגלת ספר לאוין רנ׳׳ח מש׳׳כ בזה באורך”. I cannot find this sefer anywhere. It appears to be an explanation of the סמ׳׳ג, but I haven't found it. Does anyone know what it is and where I can get it?

Comment: What edition of the Yerushalmi are you using? (Finding one that has this note could be helpful as some editions have indices of referenced works, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a work by Rabbi Binyamin Kazis on the Semag available [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21356) (note: the print is from the 18th century).

The page in question on lavin 258 can be viewed [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=21356&st=%25u05E8%25u05E0%25u05D7).

The beginning of it is the following:[image: Megillat Sefer]